# What's the difference between echo 'b' >> /proc/sysrq-trigger and reboot？

Tags: linux, operating-system

What's the difference between  “echo 'b' >> /proc/sysrq-trigger” and “reboot”？

Answer (score 2):

From the official sysrq kernel [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysrq.txt%20documentation):

> - What are the 'command' keys?
>     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     'b'     - Will immediately reboot the system without syncing or unmounting
>           your disks.

The `reboot` command on the other hand does sync and unmount your disks (as can be seen in the logs onscreen when using the `reboot` command). One difference comes with the sysrq magic: you can use 'b', respectively the corresponding sysrq key combo, even if your system seems to not respond.

See http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/rebooting-magic-way for some more explanation.